# Why do elements already created inherit the style of the new element, on ngFor in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, background-color

I am trying add a new tags, but I want that they change their background-colors .. how can I do that?

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="select">
 <button type="button" (click)="addItem(select)" 
                       (click)="setColor()">Enviar</button>
 <div *ngFor="let i of items">
   <div class="badge badge-pill" [ngStyle]="{'background-color' : 
                                                               randomcolor}">{{ i }}
   </div>
 </div>
```

---

```
select: string
items = []
randomcolor: any

addItem(item){
  this.items.push(item)
  console.log(this.getRandomColor())
}


getRandomColor(){
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}


setColor(){
  this.randomcolor = this.getRandomColor()
}
```

They are staying with the same background-colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have single `randomcolor` attribute which is shared among all of your items. Therefore, the background color may change but they all will have the same background color.

Try this

```
select: string
items = []

addItem(item){
  const color = this.getRandomColor();
  this.items.push({value: item, bgColor: color});
}


getRandomColor(){
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

In html,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="select">
 <button type="button" (click)="addItem(select)">Enviar</button>
 <div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div class="badge badge-pill" [ngStyle]="{'background-color' : item.bgColor}">{{ item.value }}
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="select">
<button type="button" (click)="addItem(select)">Enviar</button>
<div *ngFor="let i of items">
  <div class="badge badge-pill" [style.background]="color[i]">
    {{ i }}
  </div>
</div>
```

TS :

```
select: string
items = []
color: any = {};

addItem(item) {
  this.items.push(item);
  this.color[item] = this.randomColor;
}

get randomColor() { return '#' + ('' + Math.random().toString(16).split('.')[1]).slice(-6); }
```

Comment: Angular will trigger your method at every change detection cycle so the colors will always change won't they? Also why do you return a fat arrow function instead of value itself?

Comment: Check this stackblitz, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iphnjb?file=app/app.component.html When you click button, the color changes also angular gives "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError" on the console.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I edited my answer (I didn't test it, only wrote it by hand)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It still doesn't quite work though. I don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: Not work yet, they still changing the colors and show a error in console. But, I solved here! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @VitorMarcolino your problem was single `randomcolor` attribute wasn't it? Did my answer help you?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I finally take time to test it and edited my answer once again. Thanks for the heads up (again). Vitor, happy for you ! Remember to mark your issue as resolved !

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner yeah! Thanks for your help. It solved!

Comment: Thanks, @trichetriche .. I appreciate your help!